# How to determine how much memory is consumed by MemoryCache Class?

Tags: c#, caching, memorycache

Our product is based on a in-memory object data set that is held in a [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) object.

I would like to know how much memory is consumed by the data stored in the cache.

Since we might have multiple instances of the product running on the same machine 
(each within it's own Application domain), it would be important to see right away who consumes what...

The class has properties like: CacheMemoryLimit and PhysicalMemoryLimit, but no property that would let me know how much memory is consumed ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about GetCount() * Marshal.SizeOf(your type)

Comment: Doing it on my List<> of objects, I'm getting an error:
" - cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."

Comment: I see -- it seems you can only get the size of certain types.

Comment: You can do this using a debugger, that supports SOS.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to inspect memory is to use WinDbg + SOS/Psscor. Especially, [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/26/517819.aspx) from Tess will give you a script to automate MemoryCache inspection.

However, if you are not familiar with these tools and .net internals structures, it's common to spend a few hours to setup the environment and understand how it works.

Another method is to use Debug Tools 2.0, available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debugdiag/archive/2013/10/03/debugdiag-2-0-is-now-rtw.aspx). You just have to create a memory dump of your worker process (Task Manager/Right Clic/Create dump File) and selection Memory analysis. The report contains a section *Size of Web Caches in the process*.

If you want to do Live Memory inspection, you could use [ClrMD](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Runtime) from .net team. An introduction is available [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/05/01/net-crash-dump-and-live-process-inspection.aspx).